# Android 2.2 front camera

Tags: java, android

Android 2.2
I want to open the front camera and take a picture. Use the code:

```
private Camera getFrontCamera() {
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    if (camera == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.front")) {
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.set("camera-id", 2);
        camera.setParameters(params);
    }
    return camera;
}
```

But since I have not worked. How to enable front camera on Android 2.2?

Comment: It is almost 2015, why support Android 2.2(API 8)?

Comment: Android 2.2 distribution 0.5%. May really need abandon 2.2))

Comment: Yeah. I'd say so. I see you found: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net. I currently support Api 9+ in all of my applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no Android 2.2 phones that shipped with a front facing camera - the first Android phones that did have a front facing camera started with Android 2.3 - Gingerbread as per the [new features of Android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html#cameras).

Comment: If this helped answer your question, please accept the answer to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.